# Can't acces list in js conroller from apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

What I want to do is to access the lists in the js controller from the apex. Now I have only one list in apex but in the future it's many. Now List`AllAccounts`  in js controller shows Undefined through(console.log).I am not asking you to provide me whole code. I want to know why it's not working? please check the code below,

```
public class   allAccounts {
  
        public class Response {
     
        @AuraEnabled public List<account> AllAccounts {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<String> strList {get;set;}
        
        public Response() {
            AllAccounts = new List<account>();      
        }
    }

    
    @AuraEnabled
     public static Response getAllAccounts() {
        Response responseObj = new Response();
       responseObj.AllAccounts = new List<account>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Account]);
             return responseObj;
     
    }

}
```

js controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action= component.get('c.getAllAccounts')
        
        action.setCallback(this,               
             function(response){
            var responseValue = response.getReturnValue();
       
         component.set('v.allAccountsList',responseValue.AllAccounts);
                 console.log ('value'+component.set('v.allAccountsList',responseValue.AllAccounts));
                
                 
        },'SUCCESS');
        $A.enqueueAction(action,false)
        
    }
    

        
    
})
```

cmp

```
<aura:component   controller="allAccounts" >
    <aura:attribute name="allAccountsList" type="Account[]"/>
     <aura:attribute name="count" type="string"/>
    <aura:handler  name="init"  value ="{!this }" action ="{!c.doInit}"/>
   
    
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" aria-labelledby="element-with-table-label other-element-with-table-label">
  <thead>
    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
      </th>
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Totoal Contact">Totoal Contact</div>
      </th>
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Total Opportunity">Total Opportunity</div>
      </th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
      <aura:iteration items="{v.allAccountsList}" var="acc">
        
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent"><td>
      
  </td><td>{!acc.name}</td>
      
     
          
         </tr>
       
       </aura:iteration>
  </tbody>
</table>
     
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy couple of things here but let's go to the direct problem.

Why console log returned undefined:

You're trying to show what component.set is returning and not what is assigned to the aura variable.

So something like this would work:

```
console.log (responseValue.AllAccounts);
```

instead of

```
console.log ('value'+component.set('v.allAccountsList',responseValue.AllAccounts));
```

Second thing: you've missed ! at `<aura:iteration items="{v.allAccountsList}" var="acc">`
so correct one is `<aura:iteration items="{!v.allAccountsList}" var="acc">`

Third thing:

```
  <aura:attribute name="allAccountsList" type="List" />
```

You've tried to set parametered Array here (to Account) what you are returning from backend is not Account at all from the beginning, but have

> allAccounts.Response

type. If you are not solid on strict types it's easier to use List/Array (but maybe I'm biased here as Aura had historically problems with attribute types a lot)

Final thing

```
<td>{!acc.Name}</td>
```

Name should be written with capital as Javascript actually is case sensitive.

Comment: thanks, it s worked

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please mark it as accepted so another people would know it is valid without reading comments :)